# Replace file content certain line data which contains special characters through Java

Tags: java, ioutils

I have found many ways to replace particular file line content using Java and it worked fine up to certain data. When line contains special characters, `IOUtils.write()` method fails to replace those content. I'm using latest Java 1.8. Same method works fine if I use simple replacements like replaceAll FAILED to PASSED. For e.g.

## Actual file content:

```
23/350 | (PASSED) com.yahoo.getMail_01() | 11.21
23/350 | (FAILED) com.yahoo.getMail_02() | 11.22
23/350 | (PASSED) com.yahoo.getMail_03() | 11.23
```

## Expected file content:

```
23/350 | (PASSED) com.yahoo.getMail_01() | 11.21
23/350 | (PASSED) com.yahoo.getMail_02() | 11.22
23/350 | (PASSED) com.yahoo.getMail_03() | 11.23
```

## Tried code:

```
try {
    content = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(sFilePath), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

// Here yahooGetMailPath value can be com.yahoo.getMail_02()
// Replacing PASSED to FAILED is showing just as an example.
// (PASSED) can be anything else too because its dynamic value.
content = content.replaceAll(
        "(PASSED) " + yahooGetMailPath,
        "(FAILED) " + yahooGetMailPath);

try {
    IOUtils.write(content, new FileOutputStream(sFilePath), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: if you want to replace FAILED to PASSED as per your expected output then shouldnt it be content = content.replaceAll(
        "(FAILED) " + yahooGetMailPath,
        "(PASSED) " + yahooGetMailPath); instead

Comment: Don't use replaceAll. Use replace. replaceAll expects a regexp, not a literal string.

Comment: This is just an example to show, that value is dynamic and can be anything and need to tackle through code.

Comment: Please improve your question. First, you have not specified what you mean by "fails". Do you get errors? Second, I doubt that the problem is in `IOUtils`, but if it is, `IOUtils` is not a standard Java class. You'll need to add its source to your question, link to its documentation, or use standard library classes instead. Third, have you checked with a debugger whether the result of your replacement was correct before calling `IOUtils.write`?

Comment: @JB Nizet, i tried replacing replaceAll to replace but it doesn't replace the values. @ Real fail means it doesn't replace the values. I think i have already mentioned that, it works if i just use simple text replacement for e.g. PASSED to FAILED.

Comment: Show us a complete minimal example, with hardcoded inputs, that reproduces the problem.